# Optimizing query to not use filesort

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a relatively complex query, here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65c66/12/0

```
SELECT p.title AS title_1,
       p2.title AS title_2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.signature_id) AS num_signers,
       group_concat(DISTINCT s.signature_id separator ' ') AS signers
FROM wtp_data_petitions p
JOIN wtp_data_petitions p2 ON (p.serial > p2.serial)
JOIN wtp_data_signatures s
GROUP BY s.signature_id
HAVING sum(s.petition_id=p.id)
AND sum(s.petition_id=p2.id);
```

Here is the EXPLAIN (showing the number of rows I have in the real dataset, not sqlfiddle):

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key          | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | ALL   | PRIMARY       | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |     1727 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p2    | ALL   | PRIMARY       | NULL         | NULL    | NULL |     1727 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s     | index | NULL          | signature_id | 105     | NULL | 12943894 | Using index; Using join buffer  |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+--------------+---------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

At this point, the query uses so much disk space with filesort that I've yet to see it successfully complete before it errors out. Are there any optimizations I can perform to get this going quicker or more efficiently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  One thing you can do is move the join conditions to an `on` clause:

```
SELECT p.title AS title_1,
       p2.title AS title_2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.signature_id) AS num_signers,
       group_concat(DISTINCT s.signature_id separator ' ') AS signers
FROM wtp_data_petitions p
JOIN wtp_data_petitions p2 ON (p.serial > p2.serial)
JOIN wtp_data_signatures s on s.petition_id=p.id or s.petition_id=p2.id
GROUP BY s.signature_id;
```

I also think the `group by` should be on `p.title, p2.title`:

```
SELECT p.title AS title_1,
       p2.title AS title_2,
       COUNT(DISTINCT s.signature_id) AS num_signers,
       group_concat(DISTINCT s.signature_id separator ' ') AS signers
FROM wtp_data_petitions p
JOIN wtp_data_petitions p2 ON (p.serial > p2.serial)
JOIN wtp_data_signatures s on s.petition_id=p.id or s.petition_id=p2.id
GROUP BY p.title, p2.title;
```

However, why are you doing the second join?  I'm not sure what the query is supposed to be doing.

EDIT:

I think the basic query you want is:

```
select s1.petition_id, s2.petition_id, count(*) as numsignatures, 
       group_concat(s1.signature_id) as signatures  
from wtp_data_signatures s1 join
     wtp.data_signatures s2
     on s1.signature_id = s2.signature_id and
        s1.petition_id < s2.petition_id
group by s1.petition_id, s2.petition_id;
```

You can now extend this to include the petition information:

```
select p1.title as title_1, p2.title as title_2,
       s1.petition_id, s2.petition_id, count(*) as numsignatures, 
       group_concat(s1.signature_id) as signatures  
from wtp_data_signatures s1 join
     wtp.data_signatures s2
     on s1.signature_id = s2.signature_id and
        s1.petition_id < s2.petition_id join
     wtp_data_petitions p1
     on p1.id = s1.petition_id join
     wtp_data_petitions p2
     ON p2.id = s2.petition_id 
group by s1.petition_id, s2.petition_id;
```

Comment: It's supposed to get every unique combination of 2 petition id's, the number of signature_id's that have signed them, and a space separated list of those signature_id's.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index on serial? That self-join on p.serial > p2.serial looks like the only reason it would need to sort wtp_data_petitions. Try adding an index.